# Omniauth Google Account UID?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openid, omniauth, uid

I'm using the omniauth gem so people can log in to my site with their google accounts. I have it working with facebook and twitter but I for google accounts I can't extract the UID properly on the callback.

For Facebook & Twitter I can use:

```
@user.uid = auth["uid"]
```

But this gives me:

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=gXtgsdgirhGugasuzdg-asdhuzigaoWV1kgo
```

When I try to use a google account. I also can't work out how to get a photo.

Thanks!
Alex

Answer (score 4):

What it gives you is in fact the UID for your user. It is his unique [OpenID](http://openid.net) URL that he is identified by.

Twitter and Facebook use [OAuth](http://oauth.net/), Google uses OpenID. If you want the user's e-mail address, it will be in `auth["user_info"]["email"]`.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. How do I get the ID from the OpenID Url though?

Comment: The URL _is_ the ID of the user, as I said.